# SMTP Magento 2.4.6 with Amazon SES

Tags: magento2.4.6, smtp

How I can check smtp  Magento 2.4.6 without extension?

---

I set up without extension but I don't have any message by the contact form.
It looks like the screenshoot.
Is this a issue with the loggin mail?

[image: Mail Sending Settings]

[image: Loggin mail]

[image: AWS SES]

Comment: I had a similar issue and it was due to having a conflicting module with SMTP, check that. Another suggestion is to test using the different ports available in SES.

Answer (score 0):

> **I used the MAGETOP SMTP module to send email. Below is a screenshot of the store configuration.**

[image]

**SMTP Provider:** Please select Choose "Other" since Amazon SES is not listed as a pre-configured option.

**SMTP Host:** Set the SMTP server hostname for Amazon SES, which will depend on your SES region. For example, for the US East (N. Virginia) region, use email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com. You can find the correct SMTP server for your SES region in the AWS SES documentation.

**SMTP Port:** Use the appropriate SMTP port for Amazon SES. It typically uses port 587 for TLS or port 25 (unsecured). If you are using a secure connection, it is recommended to use port 587.

**SMTP Username and Password:** Enter the SMTP credentials generated in your Amazon SES SMTP settings. To obtain these credentials, follow these steps:

a. Log in to the AWS Management Console.

b. Go to the Amazon SES dashboard.

c. Under "Email Sending", find the SMTP Settings section and click on "Create My SMTP Credentials."

d. Follow the on-screen instructions to create SMTP credentials. You will be provided with an SMTP username and password.

**Encryption:** Choose "SSL" or "TLS" as the encryption method. Amazon SES supports secure connections.

**Without extension please check below screenshot:**

[image]